# create localhost connection in Oracle SQL Developer Tool

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create localhost connection in Oracle SQL Developer tool
my credentials are

```
username : SYSTEM
password : SYSTEM
Hostname :localhost or 127.0.0.1
port     : 1521
sid      : xe
```

When i connect i gives error The Network Adapter could not establish connection

Comment: Is the server running locally? Can you get a connection if you telnet localhost 1521?

Comment: how to make connection locally

Comment: check if the listener is running, e.g. use cmd -> tnsping XE

Comment: @simon it gives Failed to resolve name... what to do next

Comment: @user3331920 Please, show the content of your `tnsnames.ora` file.

Answer (score 1):

The Network Adapter could not establish connection is caused because:

1. The database host name or port number is wrong.
2. The listener process (service) is not running.  You can re-start it with the "lsnrctl start" command or on Windows by starting the listener service.

Answer (score 1):

you have either the wrong SQL Developer URL or you have a basic SQL*Net connectivity issue!  This error is most likely caused by one of these factors:

- You are using the wrong URL
- The wrong port number or IP address (or DNS host name) was used
- The listener is not configured properly
- The listener process (service) is not running.  You can re-start it with the "lsnrctl start" command or on Windows by starting the listener service.

For a step by step checklist, see the notes on [troubleshooting an Oracle connection problem](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_troubleshooting_sql_net_connectivity_errors.htm).